# C++ Object Instantiation - Which constructor is called when an object is instantiated using empty parenthesis

Tags: c++, initialization, instantiation

I am confused about the different syntax used for instantiating an object.

This is my class:

```cpp
class Object
{

private:

    int field = 0;

public:

    Object() = default; // Just for testing.
    ~Object() = default; // Just for testing.

    Object( const Object& obj ) = default; // Just for testing.

};
```

This is main method:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Object b(); // ???
    Object c{}; // default
    Object d = Object(); // default
    Object e = Object{}; // default
    Object f ( Object() ); // ???
    Object g { Object() }; // default
    Object a; // default but avoid
    Object h ( Object() ); // ???
    Object i { Object{} }; // default
    Object j = i; // copy
    Object k( j ); // copy
    Object l{ k }; // copy
    Object m = { l }; // copy
    Object n = ( m ); // copy
    auto o = Object(); // default
    auto p = Object{}; // default
    return 0;
}
```

I have no problem with the one's marked `default` or `copy`. I just want to know, which constructor is called for the one's with `???` as the default one is not called. Has it something to do with `()` initialization, as it can be seen.

I know this may not be important, but I am suspicious about it.

Can anyone help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the three declarations are function declarations, but not variable definition (as you expected).

`Object b();` declares a function named `b`, which takes nothing and returns `Object`.

`Object f ( Object() );` declares a function named `f`, which takes a unnamed parameter whose type is a function returning `Object` and taking nothing (i.e. `Object()`), and returns `Object`. Similarly for `Object h ( Object() );`.

As the workaround, for `Object b();` you can

```
Object b;
Object b{}; // since C++11
```

For `Object f ( Object() );` you can

```
Object f ( ( Object() ) );
Object f ( Object{} );     // since C++11
Object f { Object{} };     // since C++11
Object f { Object() };     // since C++11
```

See [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) for more.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually not calling any constructor.

When you change the Object class so that all fields are public (so you can view them):

```
#include <iostream>
class Object
{
public:
    int field = 0;
    Object() = default;
    ~Object() = default;
    Object( const Object& obj ) = default;
};
```

And then you try to call the empty brackets in main method:

```
int main()
{
    Object b();
    std::cout << b.field << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

You get an error because `b` is not an Object but a function:

***error: request for member ‘field’ in ‘b’, which is of non-class type ‘Object()’***

That's why, when you want to call the empty brackets constructor, you have to call it without any brackets:

```
int main()
{
    Object b;    // this is correct
    std::cout << b.field << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You identified all the constructors correctly. The three you aren’t sure about don’t do what you might think.

```
Object b();
Object f ( Object() );
Object h ( Object() );
```

All of these are **function declarations**, not variable definitions.

You declare a function `b` that has no parameters and returns an `Object`. Then you declare two functions, `f` and `h`, that have a single unnamed parameter and return an `Object`. The parameter’s type is: function without parameters and returning `Object`.

This is known as the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). Basically the C++ standard says: “If it can be parsed as a function declaration, it must be parsed as a function declaration.” Clang even has a warning for it: `-Wvexing-parse`.